# Best way to ask a question about how users got to the webpage?

Tags: user-research, web, surveys, marketing

This would be in the form on a short online survey where users will see it pop up some time after they land on the page.

I want to know the exact traffic source from which a user lands on a specific webpage, so that I can see where traffic comes from.

Some ideas I had were:

"How did you arrive on this website?" (i.e. clicking on a advertisement, clicking on an email, searching for it specifically etc...)

"Through which source did you find this website?" (i.e. same as above...)

EDIT: Thanks y'all for the Google Analytics suggestions. Unfortunately what we're trying to do won't allow us to link Analytics to account data :( otherwise I definitely would just look at those data!

Thanks!

Comment: Your analytics package should tell you where visitors came from. (Then you wouldn't a popup that most users will close immediately.)

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use something like Google Analytics to track this, instead of interrupting the user with the question. You should be able to get great insight from a tool like that.

That said, if you must include a pop-up perhaps the very bottom on the right-side of the screen would be the best placement. Almost like a very non-intrusive chat bot window. Any way to not annoy the visitor to the site.

It should also speak to your brand's voice, which would determine if it's more formal ("Take this quick survey") or friendly ("Mind if we ask a quick question?").

Answer (score 0):

We created a CampaignLinks for Mail/Advertisements/Promos, so that we can easily guess, where the user came from. Yes we should place bottom right corner to ask this question with sneaky approach.